# How do I decode Photon traffic from Wireshark

Tags: wireshark, photon, wireshark-dissector

I am using wireshark with a photon dissector I found on github to try and decode data coming out of a game that I am playing. Currently, I can get small amounts of data out of the UDP port, but there is a lot that is either hidden or unreadable, can someone help me decode or dissect Photon datapackets?

Heres an example of what I can currently see:

```
0000   f0 2f 74 22 d5 d4 b8 ee 0e 45 fc 49 08 00 45 00   ./t".....E.I..E.
0010   01 ce 4d 5d 00 00 76 11 b2 1e 05 bc 7d 23 c0 a8   ..M]..v.....}#..
0020   00 1c 13 c0 f8 65 01 ba 33 5d 00 00 00 02 f4 c0   .....e..3]......
0030   16 50 0a c1 88 d5 06 00 01 00 00 00 01 63 00 00   .P...........c..
0040   00 ab f3 04 01 00 2a 00 6b 01 25 01 73 00 09 54   ......*.k.%.s..T
0050   69 62 7a 53 6c 61 76 65 02 62 04 05 78 00 00 00   ibzSlave.b..x...
0060   05 01 00 07 06 04 06 78 00 00 00 05 00 08 09 00   .......x........
0070   03 07 78 00 00 00 10 ab 2d 5b 36 0b 70 07 42 93   ..x.....-[6.p.B.
0080   97 8c 12 14 ba 06 b7 08 73 00 0c 54 69 62 62 69   ........s..Tibbi
0090   65 73 54 68 72 65 65 09 78 00 00 00 10 c1 1f cf   esThree.x.......
00a0   8e ca b9 93 4f 90 eb 1e e0 bc 1f e9 b7 0a 73 00   ....O.........s.
00b0   00 0b 69 00 00 00 00 0c 73 00 00 0d 79 00 02 66   ..i.....s...y..f
00c0   43 36 72 20 42 e6 a8 98 0e 79 00 02 66 43 36 79   C6r B....y..fC6y
00d0   9f 42 e8 48 94 0f 69 02 cc 68 f8 10 66 40 04 13   .B.H..i..h..f@..
00e0   d1 11 66 40 b0 00 00 13 66 44 96 00 00 14 66 44   ..f@....fD....fD
00f0   96 00 00 15 66 41 40 00 00 16 69 02 cc 68 ed 17   ....fA@...i..h..
0100   66 42 f0 00 00 18 66 42 f0 00 00 19 66 3f c0 00   fB....fB....f?..
0110   00 1a 69 02 cc 67 9f 1e 69 02 cc 38 bf 1f 66 40   ..i..g..i..8..f@
0120   fd 26 e8 20 69 02 cc 38 bf 21 62 04 22 78 00 00   .&. i..8.!b."x..
0130   00 0a 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 24 79 00 0e   ............$y..
0140   6b ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff   k...............
0150   ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 25 62 02   .............%b.
0160   26 62 61 27 62 02 28 62 09 29 69 00 f0 b5 3d 2a   &ba'b.(b.)i...=*
0170   66 3f 40 00 00 2c 73 00 00 2e 62 00 2f 62 00 30   f?@..,s...b./b.0
0180   79 00 07 6b ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff   y..k............
0190   ff ff 31 62 00 fc 6b 00 1b 07 00 00 00 00 00 00   ..1b..k.........
01a0   43 00 00 00 ab 00 00 06 15 f3 04 03 00 02 00 6c   C..............l
01b0   00 00 00 00 00 00 01 25 01 78 00 00 00 1e 03 8f   .......%.x......
01c0   0f d9 3f e6 66 db 08 20 72 36 43 98 a8 e6 42 01   ..?.f.. r6C...B.
01d0   00 00 b0 40 9f 79 36 43 94 48 e8 42               ...@.y6C.H.B
```

I get some readable information, like:

"TibzSlave" = Character Name

"TibbiesThree" = Guild Name